# yum + print all available security updates that are not installed

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

regarding redhat 7 linux

the following yum syntax print the list of all available security updates  without installing them ( the installed rpm's and the non installed )

```
# yum updateinfo list security all
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

i RHSA-2015:2315 Moderate/Sec.  ModemManager-1.1.0-8.git20130913.el7.x86_64
i RHSA-2015:2315 Moderate/Sec.  ModemManager-glib-1.1.0-8.git20130913.el7.x86_64
i RHSA-2015:2315 Moderate/Sec.  NetworkManager-1:1.0.6-27.el7.x86_64
  RHSA-2016:2581 Low/Sec.       NetworkManager-1:1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
  RHSA-2017:2299 Moderate/Sec.  NetworkManager-1:1.8.0-9.el7.x86_64
i RHSA-2015:2315 Moderate/Sec.  NetworkManager-adsl-1:1.0.6-27.el7.x86_64
  RHSA-2016:2581 Low/Sec.       NetworkManager-adsl-1:1.4.0-12.el7.x86_64
  RHSA-2017:2299 Moderate/Sec.  NetworkManager-adsl-1:1.8.0-9.el7.x86_64
```

but what is the syntax in case we want to print the available security updates that are not installed

Comment: `| grep -v '^i'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:  #yum check-update

Comment: Perhaps with —security

Comment: `# yum info-sec` https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021